# Listening for change in active tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

Using Angular UI tabs. I want to know when the active tab is changed. How can I do this?

I tried adding a ng-click attribute to my tabs, but it only procs when I actually click tabs - when I change the .active tab in my code, the ng-click isn't called.

Thanks!

Comment: Try the `select` option which take a function which is suppose to be fired when it is selected, not sure it link to click only. Otherwise you could listen to the tabs array and iterate over it, if it can take activate as a config property it may (haven't check the code) set the property when that tab is active so you could know which tab is activated.

Comment: You can use `deselect()` for this and I've updated my answer with some sample pen

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `deselect()` on `tab` element as mentioned in the Angular-UI docs [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs)

```
select()  : An optional expression called when tab is activated.
deselect() : An optional expression called when tab is deactivated.
```

Here's a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGqqQX?editors=101) to illustrate the idea. Hope that helps :)